# Wordpress: how to extract a log time (serialized data)

Tags: wordpress, serialization

I have this log on a Wordpress database (wp_postmeta, if it's relevant), which is the inputs sent via a webform and that I receive as e-mail. This is serialized as follows.

```
s:859:"a:11:{s:10:"Producent*";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Test";}s:8:"Adresse*";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Test";}s:7:"Postnr*";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1111";}s:3:"By*";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Test";}s:8:"Telefon*";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"12345678";}s:7:"E-mail*";a:1:{i:0;s:12:"test@test.dk";}s:14:"Kontaktperson*";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"LOC";}s:13:"Bemærkninger";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"Yo";}s:9:"_log_time";a:1:{i:0;i:1453898700;}s:12:"_log_form_id";s:4:"1939";s:10:"_log_mails";a:1:{s:7:"Webform";s:247:"<p>Ny besked fra *URL* </p>
    <p>Producent<br />
    Test</p>
    <p>Adresse<br />
    Test</p>
    <p>Postnr<br />
    1111</p>
    <p>By<br />Test</p>
    <p>Telefon<br />
    12345678</p>
    <p>E-mail<br />test@test.dk</p>
    <p>Kontaktperson<br />
    LOC</p>
    <p>Bemærkninger<br />
    Yo</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    ";}}";
```

My question is if I can extract a log time from `s:9:"_log_time";a:1:{i:0;i:1453898700;}` in the form of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm or something to that effect? If not:

(1) How can I do that from this data (there's no other data saved)?
(2) What is this _log_time supposed to be?

Many thanks in advance for helping us newbies learn more!

PS: if this question has already been posted somewhere, please point me to the right direction, as my Google search and search here has given me nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a:1:{i:0;i:1453898700;} through `unserialize()` results in:

```
array (
  0 => 1453898700,
)
```

(Well, we could've guessed that from just looking at the serialized data.)

Using PHP's `date` function, we find out this particular Unix timestamp (i.e. 1453898700) is equivalent to Wednesday, 27-Jan-16 12:45:00 UTC.

What that date/time is supposed to mean, exactly, I can't help you with. The time the form data was submitted?

Comment: Hello Jan, thanks for that info. No wonder why I didn't get too far applying the unserialize function. I was unaware that a Unix timestamp existed. You have helped me big time! Thanks so much!